# How to check if currently running Linux kernel has been loaded with kexec?

Tags: linux, kexec

By checking I mean something quite rock-solid, i. e., trying to analyse loader's configuration or available kernel files and matching to uname's output clearly isn't an option.

Comment: dmesg or `cat /proc/cmdline` ?

Comment: I don't have kexec at my disposal to check. Hence asking to check either `dmesg` or `cat /proc/cmdline` ?

Comment: Many POWER based systems boot the "real" kernel using `kexec` from a Linux based bootloader.

Answer (score 8):

In the general case, no, it's not possible, because nothing of the previous state can be trusted, and cannot be distinguished from a regular reboot.

Just say for a example you have a system that does NOT wipe RAM at boot (memory wipe on boot is required by some secure boot specs etc); The initial boot process and every normal reboot will generally happen at the same offsets, and wipe over everything from the previous boot over time. The kernel itself will almost always be loaded at the same address.

Now consider kexec instead of a normal reboot, and realize that everything should wind up at the same offsets, and be mostly indistinguishable.

Are there special cases where kexec CAN be detected? YES!

- Kdump explicitly loads the new kernel at a different address, and
  hopes to preserve the previous kernel's memory for capture of error
  state.
- If BIOS and kernel initialize hardware differently it (obviously) might be noted since there would be changes on each boot with switch "usual/kexec".
- As a specific example of this, the EFI frame buffer is definitely
  altered by the kernel during boot, and never returns to the original 
  state on kexec.
- The corollary of this, is that if you don't control the boot of the
  kexec'd kernel, and it touches the hardware, there is pretty much no way
  to later decide if it was a *real* boot or a *kexec* boot.

As a demo, I booted a VM with a kernel, captured dmesg, then immediately did a hard kexec on it, captured dmesg again. Here's the diff between the two runs of dmesg: https://gist.github.com/robbat2/7609be2715591eac8ace3f46e852c549

Comment: > This only lets you detect the FIRST reboot with kexec — why you emphasised  FIRST? If you boot normally state would return to BIOS's and it can be detected. So each time you know whether it wasn't BIOS boot. ;)

Comment: @poige I updated my answer because this comment box was too short.

Comment: Still unsure why. kexec looks same no matter whether they're few in row or just single. In case you boot w/o kexec dmesg would be different. So that's why I see no point in this emphasising

Answer (score 4):

I just found the answer in code, and I'd like to share.

To check what was the bootloader used to load the running kernel, check:

```
/proc/sys/kernel/bootloader_type
```

One need then to shift-right 4 bits to get the bootloader_type, which is described in the following file for x86 (in the kernel tree): [Documentation/x86/boot.rst](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/boot.rst)

The kexec loader would show 0xD after the shift (from kexec-tools code, we can see it defined as #define LOADER_TYPE_KEXEC 0x0D).

It's a x86-only trick, unfortunately!!!
Hope it helps.

Comment: no need for sorry here, it's way more reasonable to provide opportunities to reply to a topic instead of urging people to skip sharing theirs findings or urging them to open new instances of the same questions. I've personally seen this on Apple's forum which I dislike a lot partially due to this limitation (but not only).

Comment: I agree with you @poige hehe
Thanks =)

Comment: Thanks for the addition, but I've seen cases where it's NOT correct, like EFI loaded systems that have the value 0x06 in that file, which would be 0x0 after the shift, supposedly legacy-LILO